# How to plot a DET curve from results provided by Weka?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, weka

I am facing a problem of classification between 4 classes, I used for this classification Weka and I get a result in this form:

```
Correctly Classified Instances        3860               96.5    %
Incorrectly Classified Instances       140                3.5    %
Kappa statistic                          0.9533
Mean absolute error                      0.0178
Root mean squared error                  0.1235
Relative absolute error                  4.7401 %
Root relative squared error             28.5106 %
Total Number of Instances             4000     

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

               TP Rate   FP Rate   Precision   Recall  F-Measure   ROC Area  Class
                 0.98      0.022      0.936     0.98      0.957      0.998    A
                 0.92      0.009      0.973     0.92      0.946      0.997    B
                 0.991     0.006      0.982     0.991     0.987      1        C
                 0.969     0.01       0.971     0.969     0.97       0.998    D
Weighted Avg.    0.965     0.012      0.965     0.965     0.965      0.998

=== Confusion Matrix ===

   a   b   c   d   <-- classified as
 980  17   1   2 |   a = A
  61 920   1  18 |   b = B
   0   0 991   9 |   c = C
   6   9  16 969 |   d = D
```

My goal now is to draw (The [Detection Error Trade-off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detection_error_tradeoff)) DET curve from results provided by Weka.

I found a MATLAB code that allows me to draw the DET curve, here are some line of code in  this function:

```
Ntrials_True = 1000;
   True_scores = randn(Ntrials_True,1);

   Ntrials_False = 1000;
      mean_False = -3;
      stdv_False = 1.5;
   False_scores = stdv_False * randn(Ntrials_False,1) + mean_False;

   %-----------------------
   % Compute Pmiss and Pfa from experimental detection output scores

   [P_miss,P_fa] = Compute_DET(True_scores,False_scores);
```

the code of function `Compute_DET` is:

```
[Pmiss, Pfa] = Compute_DET(true_scores, false_scores)
num_true = max(size(true_scores));
num_false = max(size(false_scores));

total=num_true+num_false;

Pmiss = zeros(num_true+num_false+1, 1); %preallocate for speed
Pfa   = zeros(num_true+num_false+1, 1); %preallocate for speed

scores(1:num_false,1) = false_scores;
scores(1:num_false,2) = 0;
scores(num_false+1:total,1) = true_scores;
scores(num_false+1:total,2) = 1;

scores=DETsort(scores);

sumtrue=cumsum(scores(:,2),1);
sumfalse=num_false - ([1:total]'-sumtrue);

Pmiss(1) = 0;
Pfa(1) = 1.0;
Pmiss(2:total+1) = sumtrue  ./ num_true;
Pfa(2:total+1)   = sumfalse ./ num_false;

return
```

but I have a problem with the translation of the meaning of different parameters. for example what is the significance of `mean_False` and `stdv_False` and what is the correspondence with the parameters of Weka?

Comment: WHY ALL CAPS in title ?

Comment: I think you're using the NIST DETware.  The code snippet involving mean_False and stdv_False is synthesizing random example data for  demonstration (so these are the mean and standard deviation of the scores for negative examples, when the positive scores are zero mean and unit SD).  You need the actual scores (pre-thresholding) of your classifier for all your test samples, then you call Compute_DET(scores(A_examples), scores([B_examples, C_examples, D_examples])) to calculate the DET curve for A, etc., where A_examples is the vector of indices of examples whose true class is A, etc.